# How to contact Google Cloud Compute technical support?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am at a impasse with regards to my case involving Google Cloud Compute automatic deletion of my data because I disabled my billing account temporarily. I am trying to contact technical support but it seems they would rather not be contacted. I am now seeing the same error that I called and reported initially. Their system keeps rejecting my payment card and the specialist doesn't actively addresses the problem but simply provides a plethora of documentation information that might help.

If you ever try to read documentation on Google Cloud's products you will quickly realize that it will likely span dozens of pages or more. In short, their documentation is endless. And because their products are "perfect" you must be doing something wrong. That is why their billing specialist will gladly send you a link for a ton load of document pages for you to sift and wade through, and hopefully find a solution for your problem. After doing what their billing specialist requested me to do, the workspace setup, the migration, the verification and the new email address, I am back to the original error message for my VISA card. In doing all of what I am requested to do, one has to ask the question why? The answer doesn't change: to contact technical support. When simple things start to get complicated to do then you must asses that working relationship.

It's not easy to notice these things if you were already a customer or possibly amongst the first set of customers. I remember when gmail accounts were had by invitation only; that's a long time ago. VISA is credit card provider from before I and many of you were born. They are accepted everywhere-i think. They probably handle hundreds of transactions per second. I don't work for VISA but I cannot accept that this card isn't good enough for Google's new system. I got this card for the business I am currently operating years ago. I also cannot accept that I should simply just acquire another card just to test if your system will accept. All my business expenses must come from this card because I want it this way.

I personally went into the bank's branch, to see if I could get a new card. I handed the card to a clerk and about half an hour later he handed me back the card and said he could not find anything wrong with the card. I said I know that, he then asked why I would want a new card. I could not give him a valid enough reason beyond troubleshooting GCP payment. He basically told me that they cannot give me a new card for that. For them to give a new card, the reason has to be fraud related or something faulty with the card. Besides all of that, the card date is too far from its expiration date, he further explained.

I doubt any reasonable individual would say VISA isn't safe. And when you reject a VISA card you reject checkbook money. And when you reject checkbook money, you reject the modern monetary system that is used around the globe. And by rejecting this, you are indirectly rejecting money that is legal tender.

I ran out of excuses to tell my customers so I have started partially refunding some of their money to avoid litigation. I know GCP policy most likely have changed over the years since I first became a customer. However, if you are going to reclaim your disk space then at least give notice or warning or a signal to customers(businesses) of the platform. Yes, I know your disk space belongs to you and you can take it back at any time for whatever reason but I didn't know your customers' data belongs to you. It's puzzling because my employees were the ones who made some of the softwares you deleted. So, is Google connecting businesses or destroying them? You tell me.

[image]

Comment: Frankly, if you were this verbose with Google's technical support, it's no wonder they're having trouble helping you. This is about 95% superfluous and irrelevant detail. Have you *tried a different card*, at least as a troubleshooting step?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to pay for Google services - have a look at supported payment methods.

If you happen to live from India [take a look at this](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#credit_and_debit_cards):

> Effective April 1, 2021, for customers in India: Due to new Reserve Bank of India (RBI) regulations, your bank might begin declining automatic card charges for recurring payments for your Google Cloud usage. To avoid interruptions in service, if your automatic payments are being declined, we recommend that you make a manual payment for your usage.

You can for example use [PayPal](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#paypal) (and add your card there) to pay. It's one of the officially supported methods, but check if you're in the [country that supports it](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency).

However your card may be also rejected due to two factor authentication ([such cards do not support automatic payments](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#debit)).

Maybe try wire transfer but it also [applies to some countries](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency).

But - if you have to stick with your card and can't use any other method then there's nothing more but wait until GCP support will give you a definite answer in this regard.

Comment: I have had some time to reflect on this and it is now clear to me that I am at fault. This information was posted on a public Google page for everyone to see. I should not have disabled billing. In life, some mistakes cannot be corrected. I know one day I will have to explain this to the people but right now, I just don't know how.